Create regex to find text between quotation marks, for this function
feedbackResultToast(false, result.error || "some text some text");
feedbackResultToast(false, "some text some text");
feedbackResultToast(false, result.error || "some text some text", true);
feedbackResultToast(false, result.error || `some text some text`);

I have this function(feedbackResultToast) inside my js file, I need to match them, and take  only the text group between " or ' or ` .
The regex should be written in c# .NET
I tried to do regex in c# .NET, but I can't finish it,
currently my regex:
^\s*feedbackResultToast\([^,]*, (?:result\.error \|\| )?([""'`].*[""'`])?,?[^,]*\);

For example, my regex, matched also this piece of code, that is not right
if (data.action== "edit") {

or
textBtnModal: "Add",


What are you trying to do? Can you give us some context? Maybe there is a better solution to the problem.

I'm trying to extract the text from these functions to replace it with a variable

So it's basically a "Find&Replace All" ... ?

Yes, but I can't just replace with the variable with a name, if the text is different, then I have to assign different named variables.
For example doSmth("hello") => doSmth(helloMessage) doSmth2("Jack") => doSmth2(userName) doSmth3("hello", "jack") => doSmth3(helloMessage, userName)

Is this something you need to on the fly (while the app is running)?  Or is it a one-off process?

I'm working on translating my app, and to do that, I need to replace all static text with named variables. My plan is to replace all text that matches a specific regex pattern. I've already done this for HTML tags. Now, I'm focusing on doing the same with functions.
I have a console app written in C#. When I run it, it should find all matches, replace the static text with variables, and update the files accordingly. I need to capture the static text inside these functions to complete the process

Just thinking out loud: If it were C# code, I would probably use Rozlyn to work on the syntax tree, so string literals are naturally easily identified ... I could imagine there is something similar for JS ? I just have never looked for it before, so I don't know if there is.

Note that the .* in your capture will match anything, including quotes. This means it will capture from the very first to the very last quote in your input. Instead of .* use not-quote: [^"'\]` to capture just between quotes. Note this will be between any two quotes, not matching ones.

You can use this regex in along with match.Groups[2].Value to extract the text inside quotes for your feedbackResultToast function:
feedbackResultToast\([^,]*, (?:result\.error \|\| )?(['""`])([^'""`]+)\1

This will capture the text between ", ', or `.
Friendly tip: When asking questions, try to provide a bit more context upfront (like where you’re stuck or the desired outcome). It helps others understand your problem more quickly and offer a precise solution. :)

It worked. Thanks you and  for the tip for the future
